# Dynamically allocating array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, new-operator

I need a double pointer of type DizzyCreature (my class) to point to an array of DizzyCreature pointers.  When I run it I get "Access violation reading location 0x...".  I can make a DizzyCreature* and call its member functions just fine, but when cannot run through the array and do the same thing for each obj.

I am following these instructions:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/10377/

Code

Server.h:

```
class Server
{
 public:
  Server(int x, int y, int count);
  ~Server(void);

  void tick();


 private:
  DizzyCreature** dcArrPtr;
  DizzyCreature* dcPtr;

  int _count;
};
```

Server.cpp:

```
Server::Server(int x, int y, int count)
{
  dcPtr = new DizzyCreature[count];       // this works just fine

  dcArrPtr = new DizzyCreature*[count];   // this doesn't (but gets past this line)
  _count = count;
}

Server::~Server(void)
{
  delete[] *dcArrPtr;
  delete[] dcPtr;
}

void Server::tick()
{
  dcPtr->takeTurn();                // just fine

  for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
    dcArrPtr[i]->takeTurn();        // crash and burn
  }
}
```

EDIT:
The member function takeTurn() is in a parent class of DizzyCreature.  The program makes it into the function, but as soon as it attempts to change a private member variable the exception is thrown.  If it matters, DizzyCreature is of type GameCreature and WhirlyB as this is an assignment on MI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have allocated space for `dcArrPtr`, but didn't allocate every object in this array. You must do following:

```
Server::Server(int x, int y, int count)
{
  dcPtr = new DizzyCreature[count];

  dcArrPtr = new DizzyCreature*[count];
  for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
    dcArrPtr[ i ] = new DizzyCreature;
  }
  _count = count;
}

Server::~Server(void)
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
    delete dcArrPtr[ i ];
  }
  delete[] *dcArrPtr;
  delete[] dcPtr;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's it!  Thanks for a prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
dcPtr = new DizzyCreature[count];
```

"creates" an array of `DizzyCreature`s, whereas:

```
dcArrPtr = new DizzyCreature*[count];
```

"creates" an array of *pointers* to `DizzyCreature`s, but crucially doesn't create instances for those pointers to point to.

The preferred solution is to use a standard container for tasks like this anyway though. If you *really* want to do it like this (and are aware that it's not best practice to do this manually) then you'll need a loop to call new for eachelement in the array of pointers.

Comment: The professor has not mentioned that using a raw array is not best practice.  I've seen vector used, but I'm not sure why it is superior.  Could you explain this to me?

Comment: @Bobby manual memory management is discouraged in general because it's easy to leak, hard to do the right thing when exceptions are thrown and because reinventing the wheel for the 20,000,000th time when there exists peer reviewed quality libraries that do the heavy lifting for you is nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Use a

```
std::vector<std::vector<DizzyCreature>>
```

Furthermore, if you want to use raw pointers (which I do not recommend), you'll have to allocate memory for each pointer in your array.

```
class A
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v_;
public:
    A()
        : v_(500, std::vector<int>(500))
    {} // 500 x 500
};

class B
{
    int** v_;
public:
    B()
        : v_(new int*[500])
    { // not even exception safe
        for (int i = 500; i--; )
            v_[i] = new int[500];
    }
    ~B()
    {
        for (int i = 500; i--; )
            delete[] v_[i];
        delete[] v_;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You allocate an array of count pointers instead of an array of count objects.

Instead of

```
dcArrPtr = new DizzyCreature*[count];
```

you might want to

```
dcArrPtr = new DizzyCreature[count];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating an array of pointers, but those pointers aren't valid until you set them to something.

```
double **arr = new double*[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
    arr[i] = new double[10];
}
```

That said, when starting out with C++ you should probably avoid raw arrays and instead use `std::array` and `std::vector`:

```
class Server
{
 public:
  Server(int x, int y, int count);

  void tick();


 private:
  std::vector<std::vector<DizzyCreature>> dcArrPtr;
  std::vector<DizzyCreature> dcPtr;


};

Server::Server(int x, int y, int count)
{
  dcPtr.resize(count);

  dcArrPtr.resize(count);
}



void Server::tick()
{
  dcPtr[0].takeTurn();

  for (int i = 0; i < dcArrPtr.size(); i++) {
    dcArrPtr[i][0].takeTurn();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have seen the implementation of dynamic memory allocation of 2-Dimensional array . That would have given you a better insight of how to proceed in such cases . Most of the answers has already answered you what to do . But just go through any link and see how is memory allocated in case of 2-D array . That Will also help you .