# How to create dynamic objects in member function?

Tags: c++, dynamic

In a member function of Class Championship, I try to create dynamic objects and call the member function of Class Game, but I got the error message as `error: expected primary-expression before '[' token`. How to correct it?

```
class Championship
{
public:
    Championship(string,int);
    void CreateGame();
    void display();
 private:
    int gamenum;
};
class Game
{
public:
    friend class Championship;
    void Getteam();
};
void Championship::CreateGame()
{   
    Game *game = new Game[gamenum];
    for (int i = 0; i < gamenum; i++)
        Game[i].Getteam();
}
```

Comment: Whitespace and indentation would improve readability *a lot*.

Comment: I am missing some things, like the definition of Championship. The class Game should probably defined before CreateGame().

Comment: Even a forward declaration of `Game` won't do it, since at the line `Game *game = new Game[gamenum];` `Game` must be a complete type. So, just declare the classes first, and only after that implement their functions. And, as mentioned by @Jasper, `Game` must be declared before `Championship`.

Comment: `Game[i].getteam()` is incorrect. `Game` is a type not a variable.

Comment: @vsoftco Thank you for help.I change the sequence but still got error message.

Comment: see also @CaptainObvlious' comment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically allocating array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503718/dynamically-allocating-array-of-objects)

Comment: I am really thank you,all guys.Thank you for help.

Comment: `game` instead of `Game` : a simple but subtle typo finally ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact problem you are facing in your code is in this small bit

```
Game *game = new Game[gamenum];
for (int i = 0; i < gamenum; i++)
    Game[i].Getteam();
```

The main issue here is that you have declare an array of type `Game` and call it `game` but then you try to access using `Game` which is the type, so simply swapping that back to `game` would fix that issue.

However, there is no need for using raw pointers in this way. `std::vector` is superior in so many ways here. It allows you to dynamically add more and more objects into the container in a safe way. I was about to show how std::vector could be used in your `Championship::CreateGame()` function... but I can't really work out what it is trying to do...

I also don't see why you have the `friend` line in your game class... that  is used to give another class 'full' access to your class, ie the `Championship` class is given access to private members of `Game`.

Comment: I think that std::array would be better here actually

Comment: @BrandonGomes perhaps, not quite sure what the use case is here. But it's not really the issue at hand.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** While this answer doesn't directly solve the problem, it does provide a useful alternative syntax for allocating arrays of User-Defined Objects.

This can probably be solved not-so-elegantly using the classic C-style double-pointer array (i.e. argv from int main(int argc, char** argv). Such code would first allocate the space for the array, and then allocate the space for each individual object using a loop with an index.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    //Constructor to ensure each object is unique with an int + loop
    Foo(int k)
    : i(k)
    {}

    int i;

    int operator() () {return i;}
};

int main ()
{ 
    //Arbitrary number for allocation; get this somehow
    int i = 5;

    //Although it can be unsafe, allocate an array of pointers with a pointer to pointer
    Foo** array = new Foo*[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        array[j] = new Foo(j);
        //Here, I use operator() to test that each object is unique.
        std::cout << (*array[j])() << std::endl;
    }

    //Using Coliru, the program will work and print out this
    std::cout << "this worked!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84f7641e5c4fa2f3

Comment: Thank you.Not exactly same but help.change the `Game[i].Getteam();`  to `game[i].Getteam();` the problem is solved.

Comment: Actually, this answer is pretty dumb;  I didn't realize that you weren't asking this.

Comment: Why on earth would you advise the use of double-pointer 'array'? std::vector would do the job perfectly. Of either type T or or std::unique_ptr<T> not sure which exactly unless I read more into the needs.

Comment: Yes. These other approaches do work better.